# Creating a Frame inside a Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a `Canvas`, inside that I have created a `Window` which I have packed a `Frame` into. But when I try to pack an `Entry` widget into that `Frame`, the widget is appearing on the bottom right hand corner of the frame or canvas, part of it is on the screen and part of it is off the screen.

What have I done and how do I pack `tkinter` widgets into my `Frame`?

**Edit:** The reason for using a `Canvas` was so I can make it scrollable later.

```
try:
    import tkinter as t
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as t
    from Tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):

        canvas = Canvas(master, height=450, width=450, bg="white")
        canvas.pack()

        frame1 = Frame(master)
        frame1.pack()
        MainWindow = canvas.create_window(450,450,window=frame1)

        e1 = Entry(frame1)
        e1.pack()


root = Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry("450x450")
root.title("Test")
root.configure(background="#212F3C")
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing the winow at 450, 450 in the canvas coordinate system. As the default anchor is the middle of the window you'll se the top left quarter of the frame. Try instead to place it somewhere else:

```
MainWindow = canvas.create_window(10,10,window=frame1, anchor='nw')
```

Now its top left corner is at 10,10. And you don't need to `pack()` the frame. `create_window()` is the canvas way of packing. (But you do need to pack the entry in frame1.)

Comment: Thank you so much! If its not obvious I'm new to programming, so this really helped!

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it was of use to you.